Animated cartoon movie where characters get transported from their world to ours
I once saw this animated movie when I was a kid where characters got transported from their world to ours and they try to find their way back
What I know:
It starts off as them in a race around their wee town, someone cheats and I think that's when they get transported to the real world where they are tiny compared to us. They wonder around looking for a way back when they see themselves on TV (they think it's a portal back, doesn't work). They then come across a house and they find all their race cars and inventions, turns out their part of a show I guess and the house they wondered into belongs to the creator, they end up meeting but he has no idea how to get them back.
That's all I know of this movie, pretty much the whole plot but I can't find it anywhere.

When did you checked that? Expected broadcast year or decade? Language/country?

Would be very helpful if you could add what the cartoon characters looked like. For example if they were animals & if so what kind?

Assuming that "when I was a kid" was back around 2004, I'm going to go out on a limb and assume you're talking about "The Snurks".
Here's a trailer, courtesy IMDB: The Snurks Trailer
